# What does "foo" mean in this SQL Server Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, table-alias

for eg...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ( SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY stud_mark DESC) AS ranking,
                stud_id, 
                stud_name, 
                stud_mark 
           FROM tbl_student ) AS foo 
 WHERE ranking = 10
```

Here `foo` is present...actually what it does ?..

Comment: @Raj Kaimal: `AS` is used for aliasing - table and column.  The question was what does foo represent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just an alias.

Aliases help you reduce the amount of text you may have to type out when writing queries.

For instance this:

```
SELECT customer.Name, customer.OpenDate FROM customer
```

Can be shortened to:

```
SELECT c.Name, c.OpenDate FROM customer c
```

In your example, it is a derived table (not a physical one) which now you can actually say:

SELECT foo.someField rather then SELECT *

Comment: Not only do aliases help reduce typing, but they're also essential for differentiating between two references to the same table within a query

Answer (score 6):

In this example, `foo` is a table alias.  Here's how you'd use it:

```
SELECT foo.* 
  FROM ( SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ts.stud_mark DESC) AS ranking,
                ts.stud_id, 
                ts.stud_name, 
                ts.stud_mark 
           FROM tbl_student ts) AS foo 
 WHERE foo.ranking = 10
```

SQL Server (and MySQL for that matter) will throw an error if you do not specify a table alias for a derived table (AKA inline view).

Answer (score 3):

It's a table alias/identifier for the derived query

Without it, you'll get an error because the derived table has no identifier

```
SELECT * FROM 
 ( SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY stud_mark DESC) AS ranking, stud_id, stud_name, stud_mark FROM tbl_student )
WHERE ranking = 10
```

Comment: You will only get the error because you have a where clause on the query. Otherwise you don't need the "foo"

Comment: @Jim: i can't remember: I always alias anyway

Answer (score 3):

It would be better to ask: What does the expresison after "`AS`" mean in SQL?

As Jon said, it's an alias. You can use it instead of the expression before the AS.

```
SELECT veryverylongname AS V FROM dummy_table AS D WHERE D.V = 10
```

Here you can see two aliases V for the field and D for the table.

You can also use it to alias complete `SELECT`-statements as in your example. The alias will then represent the table resulting from the sub-query, and will have the fields specifiy in the subquery after your `SELECT`-keyword.

Comment: `AS` isn't required to define an alias, but it is more explicit.